# Web page stuck with loading bar while executing the automation script using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm executing the automation script, in which I am facing loading bar for infinite time on the specific web page.

I have confirmed that issue is not from script side because earlier same scripts are executing fine.

I have applied the solutions as below.

1. Executing the script in other browsers
2. Increase wait time
3. Updated Chrome browser/chromedriver.exe

Currently I'm using below tools/version

```
Chrome Version: 89.0.4389.82
Chrome driver[Version:ChromeDriver89.0.4389.23]
Java [version: 11]
Selenium WebDriver
```

Can anyone please provide me the solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the [page load strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) to "eager":

> This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait until the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, and discards loading of stylesheets, images and subframes.

> When set to eager, Selenium WebDriver waits until DOMContentLoaded event fire is returned.

Example usage:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class pageLoadStrategy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.get("https://google.com");
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```